# Run npm command line without add node to path

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have a folder with last version of node and npm (on ubuntu) :

```
node
 node_modules
 node
 npm
 npm.cmd
```

And would like to run node/npm without add node/node in classpath

Because node/npm returns : 
node/npm: node: not found

Idea ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. 

Where have you installed node and npm?

Comment: Classpath? You probably mean system path. So basically you have a project and a node installation is placed inside that project. How was it installed there exactly?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to call the npm-cli.js using node. So in the node folder, you can run npm commands by running:

```
./node node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js <command> <args>
```

where  and  are the npm command and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

Any executable that you run by writing its name (not including the path) is looked in some pre-defined paths.

If you'd like to run an executable located in some directory, you can execute it only by specifying its full or relative paths.

If you change dir to the containing directory, you can run it by

```
./executable-name
```

In your case

```
./node
```

Comment: the probleme is 'node' is called by npm script and I can't change it

Comment: I would like to run npm (and node) without install it on VM, juste by copy the node folder